# A plugin for software reviews site like this one?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, review

I want to create a software reviews site based on categories.
I really like what Gizmo did (see link below)

http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-pc-tune-up-utility.htm

there is an Intro text followed by top 3 softwares (more or less) with pros/ cons/ rating fields.

I tried many plugins but all of them I should pre define all my fields , In other words , If I want to put 2 programs with predefined fields , I should have only created fields for only these 2 apps but what If I want to create 3 or more apps ??

what I want exactly is a plugin which I can create with it a group of fields , when I press a (+plus) button or something In my Editor , it shows the fields , and when I press it again , it shows the same type of fields again (duplication). I hope Any one could understand me because I'm not that good in English.

---

EDIT :

Finally I found what I was looking for :)

Magic fields !

Although I tried it before and I did know it can duplicate single fields , but I just realized it can create groups which can be dublicated just as I want :)

this plug in is even more than I wanted, Thanks every one.

Answer (score 1):

Its the second time i find myself recommending this plugin today, [**ProjectManager**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/projectmanager/)
is a plugin that will answer most of your requirements.

[here is a screencast of how to use it](http://randyhoyt.com/wordpress/snippets/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried it but it was not as functional as I need.
I know it can do what I asked for, but the part of inserting data sets and then recalling it in the text editor throught shortcode is not good for all users.

however I found the pligin I want , but still have problems in outputing its data in my template

have a look here
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/

it's very simple, functional and repeatable !
but very bad support :(

I'm still trying it now, If any one have a good alternative plz tell me :)

Comment: I've used simple fields and its a great plugin, maybe i can help you with it, what are the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't know how to output the repeatble field groups in my template ! what code should I put in my template file ?

sorry but I'm not a php coder :( can you help me with that ??

Comment: you ca get the meta data by clicking on "show custom field keys" and use it with `get_post_meta();` in your template

Comment: ok, I know , but this works for single fields (not repeatable groups)


you can check this link http://eskapism.se/code-playground/simple-fields/tutorial-part-2/

I used method 4 but it shows me the array (not only the values !)

here is my code


<?php $selected_values = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(), "Application", true, 1);
print_r($selected_values);
?>

Comment: that's because  you are using `print_r()` which prints the array you need to loop over that array and echo out just what you need, if you can create a pastebin of the output you are getting and the one you want I'll show how

Comment: thanks @Bainternet , but Magic forms did what I want :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out